# Are stacked (cascaded) queries in Access completely dynamic?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a number of stacked queries (QueryA -> QueryB -> QueryC -> QueryD -> AppendTable). If I run AppendTable query will all the previous stacked queries update or do I have to update individually.

I know that if I had these as sub-queries they would be run but for the moment I need to keep them as stacked queries not sub-queries.

(Sorry for the simplistic question but have been unable to find a direct answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A saved query in Access is just an SQL statement. The results of saved queries are not persisted, so each time you refer to such a query it is "updated" (re-executed) to return the most up-to-date values from the underlying data.

So, if you have a saved Select query named "SalesToday":

```sql
SELECT SaleDate, SaleAmount 
FROM Sales 
WHERE SaleDate = Date()
```

then it makes no difference whether your saved Append query does

```sql
INSERT INTO SalesHistory (SaleDate, SaleAmount)    
SELECT SaleDate, SaleAmount 
FROM SalesToday
```

or

```sql
INSERT INTO SalesHistory (SaleDate, SaleAmount)
SELECT SaleDate, SaleAmount 
FROM Sales 
WHERE SaleDate = Date()
```

you will always get the most current data from the underlying table.

Comment: Thanks, I was working under the assumption that this was the case, it's logical. But assumption is the Mother.... so was just checking.